# How to create username with firstname and lastname using feeds and tamper?

Tags: users, importing-exporting, feeds

On [Feeds tamper module page](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) (amazing module btw), it says that the module permits to [...]

Examples:
[...]

- > Combine separate 'firstname' and 'lastname' fields into one 'name'
  >   field.

But I don't find any documentation on how to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your source data, you want to use the "Rewrite" plugin of Tamper to combine the fields. More described in: https://drupal.org/node/1973776

Comment: thanks, perfect. I solved in another way using xcl and a formula (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/combine-the-contents-of-multiple-cells-HA010248390.aspx). But your suggestion is the answer to my question.